# MVC View loaded without calling the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view to set the authentication status of a user loaded from the submission of a form that is not executing the controller. When the Home-Page is loaded, everything is working without any problem (I get true for the `SuccessfullyLogged`) , but when I submit the form, the View is loaded but only the View and the controller is not executed and I get `SuccessfullyLogged = false`:

EDIT:

The structure of the page is:

```
<Layout>
   <Login Header Partial View>  
        @{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Account.LoginHeader()); } 
   </Login Header Partial View>
   <Body>
        @RenderBody() <-- GetAllByCategory.cshtml rendered inside of it
   </Body>
</Layout>
```

Logic of the flow:

```
CategoryGetAllBySearch.cshtml --> Controller GetAllByIds -> View GetAllByCategory inside of the Layout
```

EDIT:

Layout context of the Login Header:

```
<!-- Login button -->
<ul class="menudrt" id="headerLogin">
    @{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Account.LoginHeader()); }
</ul>
<!---->
```

Login Header View:

```
@model Heelp.ViewModels.LoginViewModel

<input type="hidden" id="IsUserAuthenticated" value="@Model.SuccessfullyLogged.ToString()" />
```

Login Header Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public virtual PartialViewResult LoginHeader()
{
    var model = new LoginViewModel();

    if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        model.SuccessfullyLogged = true;
    }
    else
        model.SuccessfullyLogged = false;

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

View CategoryGetAllBySearch.cshtml with the form submitted:

```
@model Heelp.ViewModels.CategoryGetAllBySearchListViewModel

@if (@Model.TotalSearchCount == 0)
{
    <p>lamentamos mas não foram encontrados resultados para a sua pesquisa<br />
        sugestões: <br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;» veja a lista de carros, motos ou comerciais a partir do menu<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;» tente utilizar outras ou menos palavras</p>
}
else
{
    <p>encontrámos <strong style="font-style:italic;">@Model.TotalSearchCount</strong> resultado(s) na(s) categoria(s):</p><!-- total results main text -->

    foreach (var item in Model.CategoryGetAllBySearch)
    {
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetAllByIds", "Ads", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "homeCategoryForm_" + item.Id }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.Hidden("ids", string.Join("-", item.Ids))
        @Html.Hidden("categoryId", item.Id)
        @Html.Hidden("search", (string)ViewBag.search)
        @Html.Hidden("location", (string)ViewBag.location)
    }

        <div id="category_@item.Id" class="innerelement">
            <p id="category-p_@item.Id"><strong style="font-style:italic;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SearchCount)</strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)<span>ver</span></p>
            <img id="category-img_@item.Id" src="~/Content/Images/ui-symb-arrow-right-green-12x12.png" width="12" height="12" />
        </div>  
    }        
}
```

The controller GetAllByIds of this form:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult GetAllByIds(string ids, int categoryId, string search, string location)
{
    AdGetAllByCategoryListViewModel model = new AdGetAllByCategoryListViewModel();

    model.Ads = Mapper.Map<IList<AdGetAllByCategoryDto>, IList<AdGetAllByCategoryViewModel>>(_adService.GetAllByIds(ids));

    model.Category = Mapper.Map<CategoryDto, CategoryViewModel>(_categoryService.GetById(categoryId));

    return View(MVC.Ad.Views.GetAllByCategory, model);
}
```

So why is the form submit not calling the controller/View and only the view?

Thanks

Comment: You already tried to put a breakpoint to the first line of your controllers in order to know of they are called by the form? If the breakpoint is working, please double-check the value of the parameters of the actionresults

Comment: What made you believe that your view was served without hitting any controller?

Comment: Can you show all of the markup for the `View` (containing the form)?

Comment: @clement Hi thanks, when I debug, the submit don't pass by the breakpoint of the controller

Comment: @RacilHilan Hi thanks, because in debug mode, the process don't pass by the breakpoint

Comment: @rcjames Hi thanks, I have updated the question with the code of the View (PartialView)

Comment: @Patrick Please notice the word "any" in my comment. What I was trying to say is: you said you placed a break point in the controller and it was not hit, but maybe it was hitting "another" controller. It's not easy to guess without looking at all the relevant code, but for instance, what are the values of `item.ListAction` and `item.ListController` that are creating the form?

Comment: @RacilHilan I have updated the question with some values, but the issue here is that, when I call this action, the Layout includes the LoginHeader and the result of the GetByIds action renders in the Body, and in this case, the LoginHeader Controller/action is not called, only when I go to the Home for example.

Comment: @Patrick I see now what you were trying to say. Your form is posting back to `GetByIds` action which renders the body as you described, and that's the expected behavior. I noticed that `GetByIds` action takes 4 arguments, which are the fields on your form, but the form is also adding yet a 5th one `id = "homeCategoryForm_" + item.Id` that I don't see getting used. But that's just a side note. Now you're saying that the "layout includes the `LoginHeader`", so please post that code because I suspect that the issue is there, not with the code you have here so far.

Comment: @RacilHilan it's already in the question, at the Login Header View: section

Comment: @Patrick Yes, that's the partial view itself, isn't it? I was asking for the code that is calling/including the partial view in the layout. In other words, post the code for the layout where the partial view is called/included.

Comment: @Patrick, if the `ViewResult` being returned by `GetAllByIds` is not referencing your layout, then this may be why `LoginHeader` is not being called and hence why you never reach the breakpoint. What is `MVC.Ad.Views.GetAllByCategory`? Is this a string containing the name of the `View`? If you are not sure, place a break point at `return View(MVC.Ad.Views.GetAllByCategory, model);` and examine the value.

Comment: @RacilHilan Hi, I have posted the part in the Layout where the LoginHeader is invoked (I can't place the all code because is very long)

Comment: @rcjames Hi, the value for "return View(MVC.Ad.Views.GetAllByCategory, model);" is "~/Views/Ad/GetAllByCategory.cshtml"

Comment: @Patrick We don't need the entire code, what you provided is enough. However, you really need to be clearer with us as to what is what, because we don't know your file names and I started getting lost. You said your `GetAllByIds` is returning "GetAllByCategory.cshtml", now is this file the one that contains the code that you marked as "Layout context of the Login Header"?

Comment: @RacilHilan Hi, I have included the structure and logic of the flow, I hope it helps you understand the problem. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick OK, this is too much. Let's try it one step at a time. Comment out the `if` statement in your `LoginHeader()` controller and only leave `model.SuccessfullyLogged = true;`. Now if you run it, do you get `true` for the `SuccessfullyLogged` on all pages?

Comment: @RacilHilan Hi, when I was doing your test, I think I have found the issue here, because the form is submiting by POST, the system is going to the LoginHeader Action with [HttpPost] used to make the authentication of the user, and ignores the other LoginHeader from my question because it has no property :S this is why it was not stopping in the breakpoint...

Comment: @Patrick Exactly. Do you see now why I asked you at the beginning "What made you believe that your view was served without hitting **any** controller?". I suspected that you were placing the break-point in one controller while it was hitting another one so you didn't reach your break-point. When you test for situation like this, you need to place a break-point in every possible controller and see which one gets called. Hope this advice helps you in the future.

Comment: Thank you @RacilHilan very much for your help and persistance in helping me. Hope I can help you also in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

After making somes test with the help of @Racil Hilan, I was able to find the issue here.

The problem was that I had two Actions called LoginHeader, one with the [HttpPost] attribute, and another without it.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public virtual PartialViewResult LoginHeader()
{
    var model = new LoginViewModel();

    if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        model.SuccessfullyLogged = true;

        MemberDto memberDto = _memberService.GetMemberById(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
        model.MemberType_Id = memberDto.MemberType_Id;
    }
    else
        model.SuccessfullyLogged = false;

    return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual PartialViewResult LoginHeader(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.Email, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        // The user is valid so it will be redirected based on the returnUrl. If null it will return to the Home-Page
        model.SuccessfullyLogged = true;
        model.Result = @HeelpResources.AccountLoginViewAutenticationValidMsg;
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid credentials, so the user will have to try again
        model.SuccessfullyLogged = false;
        model.Result = @HeelpResources.AccountLoginViewAutenticationInvalidMsg;
    }

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

In this situation, when the form was submited by Post, the system was going into the one marked with the [HttpPost], and was not doing the correct validation.

So the advice is, be very careful when you use two Actions with the same name, because the system may call the one you don't expect.